lsns reports different output based on user running it
The output of lsns looks different based on the privilege of the user running it. ubuntu user and root user get different results:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsns 
        NS TYPE   NPROCS    PID USER   COMMAND
4026531834 time        6 134628 ubuntu /lib/systemd/systemd --user
4026531835 cgroup      6 134628 ubuntu /lib/systemd/systemd --user
4026531836 pid         6 134628 ubuntu /lib/systemd/systemd --user
4026531837 user        5 134628 ubuntu /lib/systemd/systemd --user
4026531838 uts         6 134628 ubuntu /lib/systemd/systemd --user
4026531839 ipc         6 134628 ubuntu /lib/systemd/systemd --user
4026531840 net         6 134628 ubuntu /lib/systemd/systemd --user
4026531841 mnt         5 134628 ubuntu /lib/systemd/systemd --user
4026532290 user        1 134689 ubuntu /usr/bin/podman
4026532291 mnt         1 134689 ubuntu /usr/bin/podman
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsns
        NS TYPE   NPROCS    PID USER             COMMAND
4026531834 time      115      1 root             /sbin/init
4026531835 cgroup    115      1 root             /sbin/init
4026531836 pid       112      1 root             /sbin/init
4026531837 user      113      1 root             /sbin/init
4026531838 uts       112      1 root             /sbin/init
4026531839 ipc       115      1 root             /sbin/init
4026531840 net       115      1 root             /sbin/init
4026531841 mnt       101      1 root             /sbin/init
4026531862 mnt         1     25 root             kdevtmpfs
4026532284 mnt         1    414 root             /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
4026532285 uts         1    414 root             /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
4026532286 mnt         1    469 systemd-timesync /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
4026532287 uts         1    469 systemd-timesync /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
4026532288 mnt         1    572 systemd-network  /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd
4026532289 mnt         1    608 systemd-resolve  /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
4026532290 user        1 134689 ubuntu           /usr/bin/podman
4026532291 mnt         1 134689 ubuntu           /usr/bin/podman
4026532292 mnt         1   5369 root             /usr/libexec/upowerd
4026532293 user        1   5369 root             /usr/libexec/upowerd
4026532295 mnt         2 134974 root             unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc /bin/bash
4026532296 pid         2 134975 root             /bin/bash
4026532297 mnt         2 134981 root             unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc /bin/zsh
4026532298 pid         1 134982 root             /bin/zsh
4026532345 uts         1    655 root             /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
4026532346 mnt         1    631 root             /usr/sbin/irqbalance --foreground
4026532347 mnt         1    655 root             /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
4026532348 mnt         1    678 root             /usr/sbin/ModemManager
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

Furthemore the name of Ubuntu system's init process is different: systemd vs /sbin/init. What is the reason for this ? Thanks.

The output is different because an unprivileged user is not allowed to see the namespace information of other users' processes (try ls -l /proc/1/ns yourself).
Namespaces (other than PID namespaces of course) don't have an inherent "main" process; rather, lsns has to backtrack the most likely "main" process by finding all processes that belong to a given namespace and sorting them by age or hierarchy or such.
When unprivileged, lsns can only backtrack up to the oldest process owned by yourself (in this case PID 134628 of "systemd --user") but is not allowed to determine whether e.g. PID 1 also belongs to the same namespace or not.

Furthemore the name of Ubuntu system's init process is different: systemd vs /sbin/init. What is the reason for this ? Thanks.

The name is different because it is not the same process. Note the PID column indicating 1 vs 134628 – the former is the init process; the latter is not.

Ok, however even if PIDs are different, basically they execute the same ELF executable (the latter with the the switch -- user). /sbin/init is actually a symlink to systemd:
lab@ubuntu:~$ file /sbin/init  /sbin/init: symbolic link to /lib/systemd/systemd

Yes, but the point stands that they're still two separate instances launched with different command-line options (and running in two modes with different behavior, for that matter) – in particular, one instance was started through the /sbin/init symlink and therefore has argv[0] = "/sbin/init" (which not only lsns but also ps -ef or htop will show), while the other instance wasn't and accordingly has different argv[0] – and unrelated to that, it's still the case that the Unix term "the init process" only applies to the process with PID 1, regardless of its shown name or its executable.
